# Application.html.haml not rendering anywhere

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, devise, haml

I ran into this problem while doing a pinterest clone in Ruby on Rails (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abcnfFS_DS8)

My application.html.haml file isn't rendering, and it seems the only way to edit the homepage is to add to index.html.haml

layouts/_application.html.haml

```
!!! 5
%html
%head
  %title Pin Board
  = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
  = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
  = csrf_meta_tags

%body
  %nav.navbar.navbar-default
    .container
      .navbar-brand= link_to "Pin Board", root_path

      - if user_signed_in?
        %ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
          %li= link_to "New Pin", new_pin_path
          %li= link_to "Account", edit_user_registration_path
          %li= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete
      - else
        %ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
          %li= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path
          %li= link_to "Sign In", new_user_session_path
  .container
    - flash.each do |name, msg|
      = content_tag :div, msg, class: "alert alert-info"
    = yield
```

//index.html.haml

```
= link_to "New Pin", new_pin_path
- @pins.each do |pin|
  %h2= link_to pin.title, pin
```

// What my index looks like

[image: No navbar showing up]

// What the tutorial looks like at this point

[image: Mackenzie childs index]

If I was to make a guess I would say this is a problem with Bootstrap, or possibly I'm missing some code that connects application.html.haml, or maybe my versions are off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

application.html.haml is a view file, and not a partial. So the mistake you are doing is prepending the character `_` with the name of view, and doing so makes it a partial.

So the solution is: rename the filename to `application.html.haml`

**Edit:**

Other than `_`, there is wrong indentation in your file named: application.html.haml. You are using `%html`, `%head` & `%body` on the same line that is causing not to render any stuff below `%html`.

So indent `%head` & `%body` like

```
!!! 5
 %html
   %head

   %body
```

Comment: I've tried with the underscore and without and it hasn't made a difference. Now I know what the _ means though, thanks! Any other ideas?

Comment: @LeviJohnson You still have `application.html.erb`. You gotta remove this file.